# href not redirecting to new URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a desktop theme website for practicing purposes and I cannot seem to redirect my current page to a normal website such as Google. I think the problem lies with the href.

```
  <li><a href="http://www.google.co.za" ></a><span class = "icon-google-plus2 "></span>&nbsp; Google +</li>
```

I would post all the code but its quite lengthy. I have read up about the problem where the javascript may interfere but I am barely using it so I doubt that is where the problem lies.

TIA.

Answer (score 9):

your link don't have any content...
you have to wrap your span with a tag:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.google.co.za" >
        <span class = "icon-google-plus2 "></span>
        &nbsp; Google +
    </a>
</li>
```